# Why PartialView is not visible after HttpPost Action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing a solution that uses ASP.NET MVC 5, C#, Razor.

**Problem:**

I have a view that after saving it doesn't view the content of the partial view, I only see the Textbox control for Description field.

**View**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Items)
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/Checks/Views/Shared/_ViewerItems.cshtml", Model.Items)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })



@{
    var len = Request.RawUrl.Split('/').Count();
    var viewname = Request.RawUrl.Split('/')[len - 1];
    var _newprefixbuttoname = "Salva"+viewname;
    var _newprefixbuttonameProsegui = "Salva" + viewname+"Prosegui";
    //
    if (SessionManager.IsUserConnected(Xanta.ServiceLayer.BO.Ruoli.IsRole411))
    {
        <!-- saving buttons -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-right">
                <input type="submit" name="@_newprefixbuttoname" value="Salva" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" />
                <input type="submit" name="@_newprefixbuttonameProsegui" value="Salva e prosegui" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }


}
```

### -

-

**P.S.: the post method used is the same used in the other views but in this case occurs this problem. Anyway I show it to you**

**Source**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpParamAction]
public ActionResult SaveData(Valutation mv)
{
    return savingDataValutation(mv);
}

private ActionResult savingDataValutation(Valutation mv, bool goon = false)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(mv);

    var responseData = manager.savingDataValutation(base.getCurrentCompany(), mv);
    if (responseData.Error)
        ModelState.AddModelError("", responseData.Message);

    if (goon)
        return RedirectToAction(nextpage);

    setSuccessMessage();
    return View(mv);
}
```

**PartialView**

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@model Xanta.Areas.Checks.ViewModels.ViewerVerificheViewModel
@{
    bool allrespnull = Model.Items.Count() == Model.Items.Count(x => x.RispostaValue == null);
    var dropDownBMMA = new List<ListItem> 
        { 
              new ListItem { Text = "Bassa", Value = "B" }, 
              new ListItem { Text = "Medio Bassa", Value = "MB" } ,
              new ListItem { Text = "Medio Alta", Value = "MA" } ,
              new ListItem { Text = "Alta", Value = "A" } 
        };
}
<style>
    .colrisp{
        width: 100px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .norisp{
        color:red;
    }
</style>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Model.Items[i].Visible)
            {
                <tr @{ if (!allrespnull && Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta != 1 && Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta != 6 && Model.Items[i].RispostaValue == null) { <text> class="norisp" </text>         } }>
                    <td>
                        <b>&#8226;</b>
                        @*@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Items[i].VerificaTesto)*@
                        @Html.Raw(Model.Items[i].VerificaTesto)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[i].idVerifica)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[i].VerificaTesto)
                    </td>
                    @if ((Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 2) || (Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 3) || (Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 5))
                    {
                        <td class="colrisp">
                            @Html.Label("Si")
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Items[i].RispostaValue, "S", new { @id = "rbSi" + i.ToString() })
                        </td>
                        <td class="colrisp">
                            @Html.Label("No")
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Items[i].RispostaValue, "N", new { @id = "rbNo" + i.ToString() })
                        </td>
                    }
                    @if (Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 3)
                    {
                        <td class="colrisp">
                            @Html.Label("Non pert")
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Items[i].RispostaValue, "NP", new { @id = "rbNP" + i.ToString() })
                        </td>
                    }
                    @if (Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 4)
                    {
                        <td class="colrisp">
                            @*@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items[i].RispostaValue, "NP", new { @id = "txt" + i.ToString(), @class = "form-control" })*@
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].RispostaValue, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txt" + i.ToString() })
                        </td>
                    }
                    @if (Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 5)
                    {
                        <td class="colrisp">
                            @Html.Label("Non valutabile")
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Items[i].RispostaValue, "NV", new { @id = "rbNV" + i.ToString() })
                        </td>
                    }
                    @if (Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 7)
                    {
                        <td class="colrisp">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Items[i].RispostaValue, new SelectList(dropDownBMMA, "Value", "Text", Model.Items[i].RispostaValue), "", new { @id = "ddl7_" + i.ToString() })
                        </td>
                    }
                    @if (Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 8)
                    {
                        <td class="colrisp">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].CheckBoxValue, new { @id = "chk8_" + i.ToString() })
                        </td>
                    }

                </tr>
                if (Model.Items[i].TipoRisposta == 6)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="colrisp">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Items[i].RispostaValue, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 8, placeholder = @Model.Items[i].PlaceHolder, style = "max-width:100% !important;" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The partialview works very well in other contexts! But I don't understand what's wrong.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

(why you decrease my reputation...I'll have fear next time to write a new post! )

Comment: How are you making the POST? Are you using AJAX? Can you show us the code that is submitting this form to the server? How does your controller action look like?

Comment: It could be that your partial is wrapped in a <div> that is not being displayed. We're going to need to see more of your code in order to help.

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments. @swatsonpicken: I tried to remove it (Html.Partial) from All Div, but the problem is there yet! ;(

Comment: @Charles Can you show us the partial view code as well?

Comment: @swatsonpicken: sure. tkx

Comment: Could it be that your model's Items collection is empty or all the items in the collection have their Visible property set to false?

Comment: @swatsonpicken: in the Source Html code generated there aren't controls input type! But in Debug the viewmodel is perfectly full of data. It's strange!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133089/discussion-between-charles-and-swatsonpicken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's because the web is stateless, so when you initially loaded the page (via HTTPGET), you loaded all the items into your 'mv'. When you do a post (via HTTPPOST), the list of items were not posted with your 'mv', so you'll need to repopulate the 'mv' items before returning the view.